# How can we achieve Skeleton Joint Mapping feature in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In web, ImageMapster (jQuery Plugin) allows us to activate HTML complex image maps like Skeleton Joints Mapping

How can we achieve this functionality in Xamarin Forms ?
Please  check the demo link.

[Skeleton Joint Mapping Demo Using ImageMapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/examples/joints/SkeletonJointExample.html)

Comment: You can simply load the html page in a webview and achieve the same functionality as in web.

Answer (score 0):

You can use box views or geometry to display and hide from the layout when the user selects that part of the body. Since you already have the code of the HTML, you could figure out the dimensions of the image that is rendered and use that scale to figure out exactly where to place the red box. 
Looks pretty cool btw